# Post duplicately named fields to php service from c#

Tags: c#, php

This is a C# question. I have written a php service that accepts a post, does some additional calculations and then posts these calculations, along with originally send data to a final service url for processing.

There are three fields `ItemQty`, `ItemDesc`, and `ItemCost` that can be sent once or multiple times.

If posting directly from an HTML form, these fields would be defined as such:

```
   <INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME="ItemQty[]" VALUE="1">
   <INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME="ItemDesc[]" VALUE="0001-0">
   <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="ItemCost[]" VALUE="62.06">
   <INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME="ItemQty[]" VALUE="1">
   <INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME="ItemDesc[]" VALUE="0001-1">
   <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="ItemCost[]" VALUE="62.06">
   <INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME="ItemQty[]" VALUE="1">
   <INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME="ItemDesc[]" VALUE="0001-3">
   <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="ItemCost[]" VALUE="2">
```

If you were building the post dynamically from C#, how would you send these so that php would recognize these items as arrays?

I have tried these steps with no luck:

```
foreach (PaymentDetails detail in pmt.PaymentDetails)
{
    pending = new PendingPayment
    {
       //stuff
    };

    inputs.Add(new HiddenInput("ItemQty", 1));
    inputs.Add(new HiddenInput("ItemDesc", detail.AccountView.FullAccountNumber));
    inputs.Add(new HiddenInput("ItemCost", detail.PayAmount));
}
```

And this is what I tried to modify it to (first just adding [] to the hidden inputs above, then got more complicated with the changes):

```
List<int> ItemQty = new List<int>();
List<string> ItemDesc = new List<string>();
List<double> ItemCost = new List<double>();

foreach (PaymentDetails detail in pmt.PaymentDetails)
{
    pending = new PendingPayment
    {
       //stuff
    };

    ItemQty.Add(1);
    ItemDesc.Add(detail.AccountView.FullAccountNumber);
    ItemCost.Add(detail.PayAmount);
}

inputs.Add(new HiddenInput("ItemQty[]", ItemQty));
inputs.Add(new HiddenInput("ItemDesc[]", ItemDesc));
inputs.Add(new HiddenInput("ItemCost[]", ItemCost));
```